# Assets - How to hide bundle name?

Tags: symfony, assets

When I launch this command :

```
assets:install web
```

Symfony copy my asset into something like :

```
web/bundles/mybundle/img/img.png
```

So when I use this ressources, I have to do something like that :

```
{{ asset("bundles/mybundle/img/img.png") }}
```

That way, this part "bundles/mybundle/" is public.
How can I hide this part ?

I know that it's easily done with assetics like that :

```
{% javascripts '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/*' output='js/main.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

But for media (images, videos...) it's a different story. Any Idea ?

Comment: Why do you want to hide 'bundles/mybundles' part?

Comment: Because I don't want to expose the name of my bundles and the fact that I use Symfony2.  

Even the official website of symfony2 doesn't show this part :
/images/common/logo/logo_symfony_header.png

Comment: As far as I know all css, js, images, etc folder in your bundles section would be combined into a single folder (/css, /js, etc) when used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Use Assetic for images as well as for js, then set the output to wherever you wish.

```
{% image '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg'
    output='/images/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example"/>
{% endimage %}
```